# Grabbing the nodes on the edges of a matrix using modulo

Tags: python, numpy, modulo

So I have an excercise I have to make and I cannot for the life of me find how to fix this problem. This is the breakdown of the excercise:

I have got a 1000x1000 numpy matrix grid with all nodes in them either having the value -1 (empty), 0 or 1 and the excercise told me the grab all 8 neighbours from each node, with the ones on the corners grabbing the nodes on the opposite side of the matrix as their neighbours. So the most right ones would grab the most left ones as their right side neighbour. I could do this by hand but the excercise tells me to use modulo to do this and that's where I get lost. This is what I have without grabbing the edges:

```
def neighbours(grid, y, x):
neighbourvalues = []
if y >= 0 and x >= 0 and y <= len(grid) and x <= len(grid[0]):
    neighbourpos.append(grid[y+1][x+1])
    neighbourpos.append(grid[y+1][x])
    neighbourpos.append(grid[y+1][x-1])
    neighbourpos.append(grid[y][x+1])
    neighbourpos.append(grid[y][x-1])
    neighbourpos.append(grid[y-1][x+1])
    neighbourpos.append(grid[y-1][x])
    neighbourpos.append(grid[y-1][x-1])
return neighbourvalues
```

I understand what modulo does but I cannot wrap my head around how to use it with positions on a matrix. So my question to you is: can you help me with trying to get the edges correctly with modulo?

Comment: Do you know what modulo is?  Because you don't seem to have even tried to use it.

Comment: Yes I get that it returns the remainder of a divide so I get that I can find the most right row and column by using modulo on the length of the rows and columns but the most left and upper row and column both have value 0 in the matrix so I cannot use modulo cause it gives me an error that way. That's why I am asking for help.

Comment: Modulo is not remainder for negative numbers.  `-1%n = n-1`.  Besides the fact the `numpy` will interpret -1 like that naively so . . .

Comment: Ok thank you this makes sense, I can solve it now.